# How to migrate a site from cakephp 1.1 to a newer version of cakephp that is compatible with php 5.4

Tags: php, cakephp, migration

How do I migrate a site I've made using **cakephp 1.1** to a newer version compatible with my **PHP version 5.4.7**?

Answer (score 2):

Read all the migration guides and upgrade accordingly:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices.html

You can also leverage the [upgrade shell of cakephp](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells/upgrade-shell.html) or the [enhanced one](https://github.com/dereuromark/upgrade) (only for experts, though).

This should make it possible to upgrade.
But 1.1 to 2.3 is still quite a bit of work, though.